# Semicolon in Oracle connection string

Tags: oracle, powershell, escaping

this is my Powershell code :

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\oracle_script\DLL\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll")

$OracleConnexion = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection("User Id=test;Password=v79;aw;Data Source=192.30.1.5/PROD")
```

I have an issue because my password contain a semicolon : `v79;aw`

I already tried this :

```
 New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection("User Id=test;Password='v79;aw';Data Source=192.30.1.5/PROD")
```

But it didn't work, because it takes simple quotes in password..

How can I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: Use `"` instead of `'`: `'User Id=test;Password="v79;aw";Data Source=192.30.1.5/PROD'`

Comment: The rules for escaping special characters are described here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/formating-rules-for-connection-strings/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle password can be enclosed between double quotes (oracle password must not contain double quotes). The back ticks allow to escape double quotes in a string enclosed by double quotes in Powershell.

```
New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection("User Id=test;Password=`"v79;aw`";Data Source=192.30.1.5/PROD")
```

see also [Escaping quotes and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116186/escaping-quotes-and-double-quotes)