# TortoiseProc.exe logmsg with spaces via PowerShell

Tags: tortoisesvn, powershell-2.0

When I execute this command via PowerShell v2, TortoiseSVN commit window pops up, but I can see only "Latest" message, not "Latest changes". I can't find out why.

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /logmsg:"Latest changes" /path:"$loc" /closeonend:1
```

[image]

Comment: Use sextuplequotes: `/logmsg:"""Latest changes"""` (gotta love powershell for that)

Comment: It works! Thank you a lot! Could you place answer this question? I will accept your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping quotes and double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116186/escaping-quotes-and-double-quotes)

Comment: The linked question has a couple of other solutions: backticks, literal strings.