# How to add Double quotes to Array elements in Powershell console?

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0, windows-scripting

I need to display all elements of the $FileNames array in Powershell console. I am iterating in a For loop but i cant print double quotes to all Array index elements on the console. Please help.

**Actual Result:**
Dropped file:-  *"$FileNames[$i]" successfully into the folder*

***Expected Result with Double quotes(for every filename in the array):***
Dropped file:-  "NewFile1.txt" successfully into the folder... and so on.

```
$FileNames = @(Get-ChildItem $TestFolder\*.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) 
    
        For($i=0;$i -lt $FileNames.count;$i++)
        {    
            if($FileNames[$i] -eq $fileName)
            {
                $filePathNew = $TestFolder + $FileNames[$i]
    
    
                Copy-Item -Path $filePathNew -Destination $RemoteURLFolder\$FolderName -Recurse 
                Write-Host "=> Dropped file:- "'"$FileNames[$i]"'" successfully into the folder ""
```

Comment: This will never work due to syntax issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Write-Host "=> Dropped file:- `"$($FileNames[$i])`" successfully into the folder"
```

Changes made:

- To escape the double quotes you have to use `` ` ``.
- To evaluate the complete expression(`$FileNames[$i]`), You can
  warp it in a `$()`.

See also

- [Escaping quotes and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116186/escaping-quotes-and-double-quotes)
- [PowerShell outputting array items when interpolating within double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196525/powershell-outputting-array-items-when-interpolating-within-double-quotes)

Answer (score 1):

Another (quite elegant) way would be to use the [-f Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.4&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#format-operator--f)

```
Write-Host ('=> Dropped file:- "{0}" successfully into the folder'-f $FileNames[$i])
```