ERROR: How to invoke AWS Lambda function locally with base64 encoded payload using LocalStack?
I am working with LocalStack to simulate AWS services locally. I'm trying to invoke a Lambda function using AWS CLI, and I'm passing a base64 encoded payload. However, I keep receiving the error "Unknown options: response.json". Here's what I've tried:

I correctly created a Lambda function and an S3 bucket in LocalStack.
I uploaded a file (data.json) to the S3 bucket successfully.
I tried invoking the Lambda function with the following command in PowerShell (Windows):

aws lambda invoke --function-name my-lambda-function --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 --payload "{\"body\": \"eyJhY3Rpb24iOiAiZ2VuZXJhdGVfdXJsIiwgImZpbGVfbmFtZSI6ICJkYXRhLmpzb24ifQ==\"}" response.json


usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
Unknown options: response.json

Can anyone help me figure out why the CLI is not accepting the response.json file as an output? What is the correct syntax for invoking the Lambda function with a base64 encoded payload and saving the response to a file in LocalStack?

I've already tried using different syntax and checked the Lambda function's code to ensure it's set up correctly. Any guidance would be appreciated!


PowerShell probably isn't interpreting \" the way you expect. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116186/escaping-quotes-and-double-quotes, you should use `" instead.
